# Is it possible how many people visited my github project

Tags: git, github

I am created one website and upload github. How to check the how many people visited in my website

Comment: @Chris Yeah i asking github repository

Comment: Simple Google search: https://help.github.com/en/articles/viewing-traffic-to-a-repository ...

Comment: Knriano is right. Please remember to *search* before asking a question here. See [ask].

Answer (score 5):

Under repository, navigate to *Insights* tab, then click *Traffic*.

See: [Viewing traffic to a repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/viewing-traffic-to-a-repository).

> Anyone with push access to a repository can view its traffic, including full clones (not fetches), visitors from the past 14 days, referring sites, and popular content in the traffic graph.
>
> Referring sites and popular content are ordered by views and unique visitors. Full clones and visitor information update hourly, while referring sites and popular content sections update daily. All data in the traffic graph uses the UTC+0 timezone, regardless of your location.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Hits](https://hits.dwyl.com/), which is a simple & easy way to see how many people have viewed your GitHub Repository.

You just type your github username & repository in [Hits](https://hits.dwyl.com/), and get a markdown snippet to insert in your README.md repository. The result is:

[image]

From Hits [README.md](https://github.com/dwyl/hits):

> While GitHub has a basic "traffic" tab which displays page view stats, GitHub only records the data for the past 14 days and then it gets reset. The data is not relayed to the "owner" in "real time" and you would need to use the API and "poll" for data ... Manually checking who has viewed a project is exceptionally tedious when you have more than a handful of projects.